# How do I get a method and KeyEventArgs interact with each other?

Tags: c#-4.0, methods

I am trying to learn programming for fun (apologies in advance if I get the terminology wrong) and have found an issue that I am struggling to solve. I have been trying to get a program to interact with key a key being pressed (e.g: you press "space" and the console will print "hello world") and am unable to get the event and method to interact.

What am I doing wrong; is it a simple step I've missed or have I got the structure completely wrong?

Thank you!

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Key_Input_2
{
    class MainProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            KeyInput_2 k = new KeyInput_2();
            bool keyType = k.dKey_KeyDown();

            if (keyType == true)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            }
        }
    }


    class KeyInput_2
    {

        bool dKey = false;

        public bool dKey_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            while (dKey == false)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: your code simply will not work...

Comment: there is no code to receive the input.... look up System.Console.ReadKey()

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
public bool dKey_KeyDown()
{
  var key = Console.ReadKey();
  if (key == ConsoleKey.D)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
     return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted won't work at all.

First, you are calling dKey_KeyDown without any arguments, but the declaration of this method requires two arguments, `object sender`, and `KeyEventArgs e`...so the code won't even compile, let alone run.

Second, it looks like you might have copied and pasted this from some example code from **Windows Forms** coding; in this case `sender` and `e` are supplied by the Forms code as part of its event handling mechanism. I won't go into the details here, but it won't work in a Console application..you can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In the interest of helping out, here is a simple program that will do what you want, it uses [Console.ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using System;

namespace SimpleKey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //make a variable to store the input from the user's keypress
            ConsoleKeyInfo input = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
            //keep executing the code inside the block ({..}) until the user presses the Spacebar
            while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press SpaceBar...");
                input = Console.ReadKey();
            }
            //now they have pressed spacebar, so display the message
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally - congratulations on deciding to take up programming! Stick with it, you'll be glad you did :)

Comment: Thank you so much; also your semi correct; I am pretty much using trial and error and google-fu to try and solve problems (has worked well until now ;/) so TBH I thought  that "e" and "sender" were the arguments :p. Thank you so much. I look forwards to experimenting with it to work out the mechanics behind it :)

Comment: no problem...you might also want to head over here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx as they have some decent beginner tutorials for C#
And don't forget to upvote helpful answers! :)

Comment: Thank you and will do :D